# Problem creating group_by and count table with group_by variable

Tags: r, group-by, count, dplyr

I am trying to group_by 'a_sex_dv' and count 'preference_over_time'

However my output does not group by sex

I have tried

```
PreferenceOverTimeSex <- all7Wide %>% 
                         group_by('a_sex_dv') %>%
                         count('preference_over_time')
```

I put the last variable name in '' otherwise r could not find variables in the all7Wide table.

My original all7Wide table looks like this:

```
ID      a_sex_dv   preference_over_time .  
1       male       conservative_conservative_labour
2       female     conservative_conservative_labour
3       female     conservative_conservative_labour
4       male       labour_conservative_labour
5       female     labour_conservative_labour
```

The table I produced with above code is

```
preference_over_time                 freq      
conservative_conservative_labour     3
labour_conservative_labour           2
```

The table I want is

```
sex      preference_over_time                freq
male     conservative_conservative_labour    1
female   conservative_conservative_labour    2
male     labour_conservative_labour          1
female   labour_conservative_labour          1
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you group by and count for character vectors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55479277/how-do-you-group-by-and-count-for-character-vectors-in-r)

Comment: You might need to throw `preference_over_time` into your `group_by` clause. Because you're grouping by both, and then counting the prevalence of each combo.

Comment: You can drop the quotes and just use: `all7Wide %>% group_by(a_sex_dv, preference_over_time) %>%count()`

Comment: @KiraTebbe thanks, unfortunately I tried this after you suggested it but it did not change the output

Comment: @Dave2e thanks but unfortunately this reproduces my all7Wide table but adding a frequency column with a value of 1 in all the rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` does grouping for you as a convenience function, see `tally` for the version that needs you to group first. In your original code, when you call `count` it is going to override the grouping from the previous line.

You need to specify the columns to count by in `count` (and you don't need quotes on variable names). You can also group manually and use `tally` if you like:

```r
library(tidyverse)
all7Wide <- read_table2("ID      a_sex_dv   preference_over_time
1       male       conservative_conservative_labour
2       female     conservative_conservative_labour
3       female     conservative_conservative_labour
4       male       labour_conservative_labour
5       female     labour_conservative_labour"
)


all7Wide %>% 
  count(a_sex_dv, preference_over_time)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   a_sex_dv preference_over_time                 n
#>   <chr>    <chr>                            <int>
#> 1 female   conservative_conservative_labour     2
#> 2 female   labour_conservative_labour           1
#> 3 male     conservative_conservative_labour     1
#> 4 male     labour_conservative_labour           1

all7Wide %>%
  group_by(a_sex_dv, preference_over_time) %>%
  tally()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   a_sex_dv [2]
#>   a_sex_dv preference_over_time                 n
#>   <chr>    <chr>                            <int>
#> 1 female   conservative_conservative_labour     2
#> 2 female   labour_conservative_labour           1
#> 3 male     conservative_conservative_labour     1
#> 4 male     labour_conservative_labour           1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>